# Symfony render view with javascript

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

I want to render a view after an ajax call, so I'm trying it like this:

```
$("#renderContactList").html( {{ render(controller("LeymaxContactBundle:User:showContactListPanel",{'iduser': iduser,'profil':profil,'userapartements':jsonVar}))|escape('html') }});
```

but it seems that it doesn't work because jQuery throws an exception like:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Had you try with quotes ?

```
$("#renderContactList").html( "{{ render(controller("LeymaxContactBundle:User:showContactListPanel",{'iduser': iduser,'profil':profil,'userapartements':jsonVar}))|escape('html') }}");
```

Comment: it's not working , can you try $("#renderContactList").load( "{{ render(controller("LeymaxContactBundle:User:showContactListPanel",{'iduser': iduser,'profil':profil,'userapartements':jsonVar}))|escape('html') }}");